# Number of ways arranging 5 letter word from the word "Calculus"

Tags: combinatorics

> How do I find out the amount of five letter word arrangements of the word "Calculus"?

To clarify, my question is centered around the reason why that my methodology was incorrect.

Clearly in this problem order does matter,

And while it would be *trivial* to solve the problem there *was only one* letter that was repeated, the letter "u" "l" and "c" are being repeated

My initial thoughts on the problem was to do the following: $$\frac{\binom{10}{5}}{3!\cdot 3!\cdot 2!}.$$

But upon delving into the problem further I discovered that it was wrong.

I was wondering what would be the best method in solving this problem in which it has multiple letters repeating?

Comment: There is the trivial mistake that you are using 10C5 here rather then 8C5

Comment: There are numerous question about ways to arranging letters. Have you tried searching for such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider three cases: the 5-letter word has 0, 1 or 2 double letters.

- If there are $0$ double letters then the letters are C,A,L,U,S and there are $5!$ 5-letter words.
- If there is $1$ double letter then there are 3 ways to choose it (they are C,L,U),  and $\binom{5-1}{3}$ ways  to choose the remaining letters. Hence there are $3\cdot \binom{4}{3}\cdot \frac{5!}{2!}$ 5-letter words.
- If there are $2$ double letters then there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose them,  and $(5-2)$ ways  to choose the remaining letter. Hence there are $\binom{3}{2}\cdot 3\cdot \frac{5!}{2!2!}$ 5-letter words.

Hence the total number of 5-letter words is 
$$5!+3\cdot \binom{4}{3}\frac{5!}{2!}+
\binom{3}{2}\cdot 3\cdot \frac{5!}{2!2!}=1110.$$